# Confirm Validation before save in Zend Frame work 1.12

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, zend-framework

I have a form and validations to the form. To save the data I used a function to save it using ajax. This is my form

```
    <form name="enquiry_form"  method="post" id="enquiry_form">
        Full Name: <input name="name" id="name" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{1,20}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plz enter only Alphabets ')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"> 
        Email: <input  name="email"  id="email" type="email"  oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plz enter valid email ')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" required   >
         Phone: <input name="mobile"  id="mobile" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10,12}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plz enter valid Mobile Number ')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" required >
         Query: <textarea name="query"  id="query" class="" required></textarea></li> 
         <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"  id="enq_submit" onclick="getEnquiryForm(); ">                           
            </form>
```

***This my getEnquiryForm() function***:

```
    getEnquiryForm: function()
{
        var url = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/'+path.base_path+'/ajax/save-enquiry'; //url path
            new Ajax.Request(url,
            {
                parameters: $('enquiry_form').serialize(),
                method:'POST',
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    //alert(transport.responseText);

                },
                onFailure: function(transport) {
                    alert('Could not connect to Propladder Server for this request');
                },
                onComplete: function(transport) {
                }
            });
},
```

Then my ajaxController in which I have ***saveEnquiry()*** action mentioned in the url above in the function

```
    public function saveEnquiryAction()
{
    $data = array();
            $data['name'] = $this->_getParam('name');
            $data['email'] = $this->_getParam('email');
            $data['mobile'] =$this->_getParam('mobile');
            $data['query'] =$this->_getParam('query');  
    $mapper = new Application_Model_EnquiryMapper();
        $mapper->save($data); 
}
```

After I click the submit button and if the validations are false it is immediately moving to the function and getting saved in database, and also its showing validation alerts and after giving inputs with validations true the data is getting saved again. By this my form is getting saved multiple times. Instead of this the cursor should be moved to the ***getEnquiryForm()*** or ***saveEnquiryAction()*** only when all  the form validations are true

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a Zend_Form and validate it?

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.html

Or you could directly use the abstract class **Zend_Validate** to check if a validation is passed or not. And build a error array to show the user errors in the view

```
$errors = array();

$name = $this->_getParam('name');

/** @see Zend_Validate */
// Zend_Validate::is($value,$baseClassName);
// baseClassName: NotEmpty, EmailAddress, Uri, GreaterThan, LessThan

if(Zend_Validate::is($name,'NotEmpty')) {
    $data['name'] = $name;
}
else {
    $errors['name'] = 'Empty';
}
if(Zend_Validate::is($name,'EmailAddress')) {
    $data['email'] = $email;
}
else {
    $errors['email'] = 'Not an email';
}
...

$enquiryMapper = new Application_Model_EnquiryMapper();
//check if existing?
$enquiry = $enquiryMapper->fetchByEmail($email);
if($enquiry) {
    $errors['email'] = 'Email existing';
}
...
//check if no errors are occured
if(!count($errors)) {
    //save your model
    $data = array();
    $data['name'] = $this->_getParam('name');
    $data['email'] = $this->_getParam('email');
    $data['mobile'] =$this->_getParam('mobile');
    $data['query'] =$this->_getParam('query');  

    $enquiry = $enquiryMapper->save($data); 
}
...
$this->view->enquiry = $enquiry; //used to check if saved correctly
$this->view->errors = $errors; //used to show errors in the view (foreach)
```

**But i highly recommend you to use a Zend_Form Object and the validators and filters.**

You will get filtered clean values and have automatically translated (if Zend_Locale is set) error messages.

**Zend_Form via new in controller**

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setAction("");
$form->setMethod('POST');

$name = $form->createElement('text','name',array(
    //'label' => 'Name:',
    'placeholder' => 'Name',
    'required' => true,
    'validators'    => array(
        array(new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty(), true),
        array(new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('min' => 1,'max' => 64)),true)
    ),
    'filters' => array()
));

$form->addElement($name);
...

$form->addElement('button', 'submit', array(
    'label' => "Save"
));

$this->view->form = $form;
```

**Or extend Zend_Form in application/forms/Test.php**

```
class Application_Form_Test extends Zend_Form {
    public function init() {
         $this->setAction("");
         $this->setMethod("POST");

         $name = $this->createElement('text','name',array(
             //'label' => 'Name:',
             'placeholder' => 'Name',
             'required' => true,
             'validators'    => array(
                 array(new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty(), true),
                 array(new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('min' => 1,'max' => 64)),true)
             ),
             'filters' => array()
         ));

        $this->addElement($name);
        //...
        $this->addElement('button', 'submit', array(
            'label' => "Save"
        ));
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$form = new Application_Form_Test(); //or directly create like shown above

$request = $this->getRequest();

if($request->isPost()) {
    //validate form (auto render errors)
    if($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
        //form is valid... 
        //check for existing objects by email, name, phone, etc
        //save your object to db
    }
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

**In View**

```
echo $this->form;
```